# What is swamp milk?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

Pavlo Tychyna's poem *Enharmonies* starts as follows:

> Above the swamp milk is spun...
> A black raven lost in thought
> A grey raven is musing
> It pecked out eyes. God knows whose.

I'm confused by this, though. What is "swamp milk"? Also, what is a grey raven?

Comment: Couldn't it be "Above the swamp, milk is spun"? (Still leaves open the question of what it means to spin milk, though.)

Comment: Is this a translation? And if so, are you fluent in the original language? Perhaps the original language might have more inflection/declension/conjugation to offer insights on the correct parsing.

Comment: @shoover I unfortunately don't read any Ukrainian :(

Comment: original text: http://ukrbooks.com/ua/Engarmonijne_tuman/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Enharmonies" is divided into four parts: Fog, Sun, Wind, and Rain. As the stanza quoted is from the first part,"Fog", it seems likely that the "spun milk" is simply a description of the fog swirling above the swamp. Describing fog as milk-like is fairly common in poetry.